# How can I compute the derivative $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{x}^{\infty} e^{-t^2/2}\ dt$?

Tags: calculus

Rewriting and using the fundamental theorem of calculus:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} \left(\lim_{M \to \infty} \int_x^M e^{-t^2/2}\ dt \right) &= \frac{d}{dx} \left(\lim_{M \to \infty} - \int_M^x e^{-t^2/2}\ dt \right) \\
&= \lim_{M \to \infty} -\frac{d}{dx}\int_M^x e^{-t^2/2}\ dt \\
&= \lim_{M \to \infty} -e^{-x^2/2} \\
&= -e^{-x^2/2}.
\end{align*}
Is the above correct? The integrand is continuous so I think using the FTC is valid. Can I swap limits safely as I do above?

Comment: One way to work around the limit-swapping would be to write $\int_x^M e^{-t^2/2} \, dt=\int_x^0 e^{-t^2/2} \, dt + \int_0^M e^{-t^2/2}$. Then the first term falls out of the limit because it's independent of $M$, but the limit of the second term has derivative zero because it's independent of $x$...

Comment: Hint: write $$
\int_x^{ + \infty }  = \int_0^{ + \infty }   - \int_0^x .
$$

Comment: $$\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}h(x) 
&= \frac{d}{dx}\int_{f(x)}^a g(t)dt\\
& =\frac{d}{dx}\left[G(t)\right]_{f(x)}^{a}\\
& = \frac{d}{dx}\left(G(a)-G(f(x))\right)\\
& = -g(f(x))\times f'(x)
\end{align*}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x}^{\infty}e^{-t^2/2 } =  -e^{-x^2/2}$$
If you are looking for something like the fundamental theorem of improper integral then this is something I have no idea about.